# Определить, сколько слов в строке разделяются более чем одним пробелом

Tags: c#

```
count=1;
for(int i = 0; i<s.Length-1;i++)
            {
                if (s[0] == ' ' && s[1] == ' ') continue;
                if (s[i] == ' ' && s[i + 1] == ' '&&s[i+2]!=' ') count++;
            }
```

Вот как бы работает.

Но если ввести строку таким образом(цифры в кавычках - пробелы):
слово’2’слово’4’слово’3’слово’1’слово’10’слово

То оно считает неправильно.

Comment: это ваша задача и мы вам желаем удачи с ней, а вопрос то в чем?

Comment: так вам надо слова посчитать или количестиво интервалов между словами с 2 и более проблеми?

Comment: `То оно считает неправильно.` как вы это поняли? Сколько получилось и сколько должно быть?

Comment: конечно неправильно, потому что это код считает количество тройных пробелов, причем ``    `` (4 пробела) будут считаться за два раза по три пробела. А потом еще и ошибку доступа выдаст.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 2; i < s.Trim().Length; i++)
{ 
    if (s[i]==' '&& s[i-1] == ' '&&s[i-2]!=' ')
    {
        count++;
        while (s[i] == ' ' && (i + 1) < s.Trim().Length && s[i + 1] != ' ') i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]